# Kernel module not compiling

Tags: makefile, kernel

Below is the code to my module:

```
#include<linux/modules.h>   //needed by all modules
#include<linux/kernel.h>     //neede for kern_info

int init_module(void)               //initialisation module
{
printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world1 \n");

return 0; //non zero return means the initialisation was not successful
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
printk(KERN_INFO "Good Bye \n");
}
```

Below is the Makefile:

```
obj−m += kernel.o

all:
make −C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
make −C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

When I try to run make command there is an error "*** No rule to make target `−C'.  Stop."

Please Help.

Comment: Commands in the makefile should be tab-indented(`<tab>make -C ...`).

Comment: They are tab indented in the original file.

Comment: Then edit you question so, that its code corresponds to your original file. According to error message It is a high chance that you have incorrect formatting in you code.

Comment: @LALITDUDHERIA You might think they are tab indented, but maybe your editor has expanded tabs to spaces. To be sure, you have to use an editor which can show tabs clearly, like `:set list` mode in Vim.  Decent programming editors can also flag whitespace problems in Makefiles with syntax highlighting.

Comment: If it's complaining about -C, then I would hazard to guess that the dash in the -C is a windows dash as opposed to ascii character 45.  Try to manually retype those lines to see if it fixes the problem.